# import script into __init__.py from subdirectory

Tags: python

I am struggling with importing a script from a sub sub folder

I have the `__init__.py` in folder X. Inside folder X there is folder Y and in folder Y is folder Z

I have a script in folder Z that I need to import.

To import from folder Y I use `from .Y import script`

Now I want to import from Z so i tried

```
from .y/z import script
from .Y//z import script
from .y\z import script
```

None of them works

How can I import scripts from folder Z?

Comment: `from .Y.Z import script`

Comment: Please place it as answer so I can accept it for you.|
Earns you some credits

Answer (score 1):

Inside python , you refer to directories by placing `.` just like java, unlike C++.
You should try 
`from y.z import script`
 instead of
`from y/z import script`.
Moreover this is a very basic python problem, I'd recommend learning python for some time before jumping into making blender addons.